# Alias a mysql table for a session?

Tags: mysql

I know you can give an alias to a table for a query, like `SELECT 1 FROM table AS t` but is there a way to give an alias to a table for a session?

The use case is I have a "query pattern" that should apply to 3 different tables. So I would like to make only one query, using a table alias, and then tell mysql "Execute this query considering that is alias is table1, then execute the same query considering the alias is table2,..."

The use case:

```
INSERT INTO aliasedTable (id, value) VALUES (1,1)
```

The tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT UNSIGNED, value TINYINT UNSIGNED)
CREATE TABLE table2 (id INT UNSIGNED, value TINYINT UNSIGNED)
CREATE TABLE table3 (id INT UNSIGNED, value TINYINT UNSIGNED)
```

The "supposed" syntax

```
ALIAS table1 AS aliasedTable;
INSERT INTO aliasedTable (id, value) VALUES (1,1)
ALIAS table2 AS aliasedTable;
INSERT INTO aliasedTable (id, value) VALUES (1,1)
ALIAS table3 AS aliasedTable;
INSERT INTO aliasedTable (id, value) VALUES (1,1)
```

What I thought of, is making a updatable `VIEW` of the table, but there is no such thing like `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW ...`. And using a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE aliasedTable AS (SELECT * FROM table1)` would create a table copy, instead of inserting in the original table.

Any suggestion?

---

Note that I have such case in a PHP code, but also in a procedure:

```
<?php
$query = 'INSERT INTO aliasedTable (id, value) VALUES (1,1)';
foreach (array('table1', 'table2', 'table3') AS $t) {
    // Ideally, I would like to avoid string concat here and tell MySQL
    // something like 'ALIAS :placeholder AS aliasedTable', ['placeholder' => $t]
    $pdo->query('ALIAS ' . $table1 . ' AS aliasedTable');
    $pdo->query($query);
}
```

or

```
SET @tables := '["table1","table2","table3"]';
SET @i := JSON_LENGTH(@tables) - 1;
WHILE (@i >= 0) DO 
    SET @table := JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@tables, CONCAT('$[', @i, ']')));
    ALIAS @table AS aliasedTable;
    CALL inserting();
    SET @i := @i - 1;
END WHILE;
```

where

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserting() 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO aliasedTable (id, value) VALUES (1, 1);
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is switch to a dynamic SQL statement and pass the table name as an input argument to the `inserting` function:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserting( IN tbl_name VARCHAR(25) )
BEGIN
SET @stmt = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', tbl_name, ' (id, value) VALUES (1, 1)');
 PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Depending on your call this will insert data to appropriate table. As an example:

```
CALL inserting('table1');
```

will execute following statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, value) VALUES (1,1);
```

Then from PHP you could call this procedure for each element in your array passing the current element as an argument to the function.

Comment: That's how we're going for now, but my concern here is that `tbl_name` could be a non-existing table, or worst, end up being user-defined: a non-expected table (`information_schema.*` ) might be used, or a SQL injection. Not to mention that the IDE is pretty lost in such case

Comment: You can create a table which will store all table names that you allow to be used within the procedure and check if it's from the allowed list. I wouldn't be concerned about SQL injection, because preparing a statement only allows one statement at a time - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html. Also, you could specify a schema in the procedure INSERT statement from which the tables can be picked up.